# Create javascript object with event handler

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a JavaScript Object and named it 'Button'. this object has a function that draw a button and append it to specific div element.

```
  var Button = function (id, value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;           

        this.draw = function () {
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "button";
            element.id = id;
            element.value = value;               
            document.getElementById("topDiv").appendChild(element);
        }
    };
```

I instantiate Button object and call draw() function like this:

```
 var myButton = new Button('btn1', "Test Button");
 myButton.draw();
```

My problem is I cant handle events. I want to connect onclick event to a function. for example:

```
myButton.onClick = function(){ alert(1); };
```

but I don't know how to define this.

Comment: You are “attaching” an event on the JavaScript object here – you want to attach it to the DOM element instead (`element` in your `draw` method). So you either have to provide outside access to that element (make it a public property f.e.) – or, if you need the same event handling for all those buttons, just attach the handler inside your Button function already, when creating the element.

Comment: I dont want onclick event create by default. I want it to create when I want to. And i do have access to my element in my object constructor. I have it's name. 

var element= document.getElementById(id);
 element.onclick = function () {
     alert('blah blah');
  };

this works. by I want to pass the a function and when I push the button, my specific function calls.

Comment: @Azade: Yes, it would be just `document.getElementById(myButton.id).onclick = …` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var Button = function (id, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;           

    this.draw = function () {
        this.element = document.createElement("input");
        this.element.type = "button";
        this.element.id = id;
        this.element.value = value;               
        document.getElementById("topDiv").appendChild(this.element);
    }
};

Button.prototype.addEventListener = function(event, handler){
    var el = this.element;
    if(!el){
        throw 'Not yet rendered';
    }
    if (el.addEventListener){
        el.addEventListener(event, handler, false); 
    } else if (el.attachEvent){
        el.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mPHXw/)

Comment: I don't want to send my handler as a parameter. I want it to be assigned. like myButton.click = function(){...};
by the way it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but it's worth mentioning that you could have done it after appending to div:

```
document.getElementById("topDiv").appendChild(element);
this.element.onclick = function(){ alert(1);};
```

this is more consistent and much less coding.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8byy75o/)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own click() method (which takes a function as a parameter) that binds to the DOM element's click handler. Your draw() method can store a reference to the element in the object instance so that your click() method can access it.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned, you should attach events to DOM objects.

The simple way is just to expose your DOM element from your custom class:

```
var Button = function (id, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;

    var element = document.createElement("input");
    this.element = element;           

    this.draw = function () {
        element.type = "button";
        element.id = id;
        element.value = value;               
        document.getElementById("topDiv").appendChild(element);
    }
};
```

Now you can:

```
 var myButton = new Button('btn1', "Test Button");
 myButton.draw();
 myButton.element.onclick = function(){ alert(1); };
```

Answer (score 0):

If Native Javascript....

```
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick
```

If jQuery

```
$('#btn1').click(//function(){})....
```

If jQuery but Button is Created dynamically....
You might try..

```
$('#btn1').live('click',//function(){ })....
```

EDIT: As Suggested in the Comment:
Please read what the Documentation says:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().
>
> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the
>   document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers
>   when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of
>   direct versus delegated events in the .on() method for more
>   information.

*Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:*

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7+
```

**ADDITIONAL**
If You can't live without -live-...

> As of jQuery 1.4 the .live() method supports custom events as well as
>   all JavaScript events that bubble. It also supports certain events
>   that don't bubble, including change, submit, focus and blur.

Comment: Avoid live. It's deprecated and performs poorly.

Comment: I'm trying to create a JavaScript library. I don't want to use document.getElementById... or any of this.

Comment: @ertrne it's Good when You say Avoid -SODA-... drink -WATER- instead.. Yah, he is gonna avoid 'live' as the SODA.... What's the WATER to drink instead??. The Documentation says: --As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page. "--- IF He is still using jQ < 17....there is NO HARM..